# Python: howto execute the content of a string as an attribute of an object

Tags: python, exec

I have tried running this code:

```
for col1 in df.columns:
    for col2 in df.columns:
        if col1 != col2:
            print col1 + ' and ' + col2
            gb = df.groupby(col1)
            run_line = 'gb.' +  col2 + '.value_counts()'
            count = exec run_line
            print count
```

and I get this error:

```
 File "<ipython-input-21-6bcce6d6c562>", line 7
    count = exec run_line
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any help how I can store the result of

```
exec run_line
```

or how I can run

```
gb.col2.value_counts()
```

using the content of the variable col2

Answer (score 1):

Generally you want to avoid using `exec`. Luckily for what you are doing, you don't *need* `exec`. If you just need to access an attribute on an object that isn't specified until runtime, use `getattr`:

```
for col1 in df.columns:
    for col2 in df.columns:
        if col1 != col2:
            print col1 + ' and ' + col2
            gb = df.groupby(col1)
            col2_attr = getattr(gb, col2)
            count = col2_attr.value_counts()
```

Note that the last line will raise an `AttributeError` if you `col2_attr` doesn't have a `value_counts` method.

Comment: Good! that did the trick. I am new to python and really new to pandas.